# Bash curl how to set up variable in header?

Tags: bash, curl

I faced with problem when created simple bash script, so, my goal - fect jwt token and will use tokn in next query, For that first curl fetch credentials from `login.json` file and then set it in `result.json`, then reed `token` key and set it in variable `tokenValue` then I want to set it on bext curl in header but when I debugged I did not get `Authorization` header, why ? When I substitute the variable manually (like `"Authorization: Bearer test_token"`) - it's worked, I faced with `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=Bearer test_token`

```
curl --request POST -sL \
     --url 'http://auth.loc/api/login'\
     --output './result.json' \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d "@login.json" \

tokenValue=$(jq -r '.token' './result.json')
bearerToken="Authorization: Bearer "$tokenValue
echo 'fff' + $bearerToken

curl --request GET -sL \
     --url 'http://qbee.local/api/v2/grouptree?_format=json'\
     --output './grouptree_result.json' \
     --header $bearerToken \

echo "$(cat grouptree_result.json)"
```

`echo 'fff' + $bearerToken` works fine, I faced with correct data in cli

Comment: Make sur you don't get a `CR` in `$bearerToken`.  On another note, maybe you should also add a `Content-Type` header.

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to resolve it. Problem was with double and single quotes

```
curl --request POST -sL \
 --url 'http://qbee.local/api/v2/login'\
 --output './result.json' \
 --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -d "@login.json" \

tokenValue=$(jq -r '.token' './result.json')

echo 'token was' + $tokenValue

curl --request GET -sL \
     --url 'http://qbee.local/api/v2/metric/1587260952123_10?type=group'\
     --output './metric_result.csv' \
     --header 'Authorization: Bearer '"$tokenValue" \
     --header 'Content-Type: csv' \

echo "$(cat grouptree_result.json)"
```

Comment: `--header "Authorization: Bearer $tokenValue"`